# Как в Node.js проверить нагрузку на сервер (localhost)

Tags: javascript, node.js

Хочу проверить нагрузку на сервер Node.js, который находиться у меня на localhost - мой компьютер. Если пакет какай-то который это позволяет ?

Хочу узнать сколько человек может зайти ко мне на сайт.

Answer (score 0):

Можно глобально установить один из пакетов:

[StrongLoop Process Manager](https://strong-pm.io)

```
 npm i -g strongloop
```

[PM2](https://pm2.keymetrics.io)

```
 npm i -g pm2
```

[Forever](https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever)

```
 npm i -g forever
```

Достаточно запустить ваш проект через один из этих менеджеров и вы получите детальную статистику в реальном времени. В случае с pm2 достаточно в консоль ввести `pm2 monit` чтобы отобразить статистику.

Так же они позволяют в автоматическом режиме запускать приложение если они упали, запускать и контролировать лимиты памяти используемые вашим приложением node.js